# rails find_by_all attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's have a table `elements` with many string columns (`c1, c2, c3`)

Is there a **rails way** to find_by_all(my_string) where at least one of columns is set to "my_string" without listing all of them instead of querying like this :

```
Element.where(c1: "my_string").or.where(c2: "my_string").or.where(c3: "my_string")
```

or

```
Element.find_by_c1("my_string") || Element.find_by_c2("my_string") || Element.find_by_c3("my_string")
```

(I know i can use sql trick like: `Element.where(CONCAT_WS('|', c1, c2, c3) LIKE '%my_string%')`, but it's not really railzy)

Comment: No I don't think so . I'd go with the third option you listed. It's OK to break out of activerecord for some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to list all of columns you want to query.

```
columns = %w(c1 c2 c3)
```

Or use `column_names` method

```
columns = Element.column_names
```

then use [rails_or](https://github.com/khiav223577/rails_or) and do it like

```
str = 'my_string'
columns.inject(Element.where(0)){|model, col| model.or(col => str) }
```

Note that you may want to exclude none-string columns like `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`:

```
columns -= %w(id created_at updated_at)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like following (Of course if string is same)

```
Element.where('c1= :var OR c2= :var OR c3= :var', { var: 'my_string' })
```

For all the columns

```
Element.where(%w(c1 c2 c3).map{|col| "#{col} = :var"}.join(' OR '), { var: 'my_string' })
```